# How does one protect a webapp to be accessed only by localhost?

Tags: security, deployment, jakarta-ee, solr, web-applications

I am planning to run a **java web application** and **solr** in the same java container. I want the web application to be publicly accessible but solr to be accessible only to the other web applications in the same container. Solr should be accessible only as localhost and not from outside. Can we write some rules in the web-xml to achieve this?

Comment: This is very dependent on the servlet container. For Apache Tomcat, I believe this is possible. For other containers, I do not know. Please specify the container to get a better answer.

Comment: I am looking for a answers on Resin/Tomcat/Jetty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a question for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/). Anyway, you can deal with this the same way you deal with any internal server, like a database server: don't give Solr a public IP, or put it behind a firewall.

Other than that, you could set up HTTP auth ([Tomcat example](http://blog.comtaste.com/2009/02/securing_your_solr_server_on_t.html)) or set the container to only listen on localhost (that is, if your web app runs on the same box) ([jetty example](http://www.midgard-project.org/documentation/how_to_set_up_site_search_using_solr/#2fae32629d4ef4fc6341f1751b405e45)), but I recommend putting it behind a properly configured firewall instead.

Also see the [SolrSecurity wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity), but it deals mostly with Solr-level security.

Comment: Mauricio: Is it possible to allow only my PHP code to access Solr via IPTables? Do you know the rules for this in IPTables?

Comment: Also, check this Q out: http://serverfault.com/questions/146568/solr-security-help The answer there applies to Resin, but I am using Jetty, will that matter? Thanks for all help

Answer (score 1):

For Resin you can define security constraint by ip addresses. Below is sample from Resin 2.X I'm using it might be slightly different for Resin 3 or 4

```
<host id='solr.mydomain.com' app-dir='/dev/null'>
   <env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>/usr/local/java/solr-home</env-entry-value>
  </env-entry>
   <security-constraint>
     <web-resource-collection>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </web-resource-collection>
     <ip-constraint>127.0.0.1</ip-constraint>
     <ip-constraint>192.168.1.0/24</ip-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
   <war-dir>webapps/solr</war-dir>
   <access-log id='log/solr-access.log'
     format='%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i"'/>
   <error-log id='log/solr-error.log'/>
</host>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this link on the Solr wiki that details installation procedures and also ways of securing the application. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall