# Solr; "rookie" question

Tags: java, php, mysql, database, solr

I have a SolrPhpClient on my classifieds website, and whenever users wants to add/remove classified the index in Solr gets updated via Php code.

So I wonder, does this mean that my Solr index is open for anybody to alter with?

Same Q applies to the Solr Admin page.
If I set a password for the admin page, does this mean that my classifieds website wont have access to updating/removing documents from the Solr index?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183497/how-does-one-protect-a-webapp-to-be-accessed-only-by-localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Solr instance is available to the public so that anyone can make an http connection to it, you are vulnerable.

Think of Solr as a back-end service (like your MySql database).  You should prevent all public access to the Solr instance.  You can run a firewall or do some IPTables magic to allow only your PHP application to connect to Solr (and obviously your administrator to connect to the admin interface).

Comment: In basic terms, how can I allow only my php app to have access to solr? Would appreciate details.

Comment: SOLR authentication was added to SOLR at some point after this question :) https://lucidworks.com/blog/2015/08/17/securing-solr-basic-auth-permission-rules/